# Database schema for Facebook, Google and my own authentication

Tags: database, facebook, authentication, database-design, google-plus

I want to accomplish nearly the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817744/database-schema-for-multiple-authentications-facebook-connect-twitter-openid), which is to store authentication data from multiple sources (Facebook, Twitter, my own app, etc.) so that one person can log in to their account from any/all of the mentioned providers.

Following, I posted a screenshot of my two created tables.

[image: Database Schema]

The table "identity" will be responsible to store the login method (Facebook, Google or my own login system). An user can have one or more "identity".

In the table "identity", the column "adapter" will store the authentication method (facebook, google, myapp). The "hash" column will store the ID of the authentication method (for Google or Facebook), or if it's a record of my own app authentication method, the "hash" colunm will store the user registered password encrypted with SHA1.

My question is, for example: How can I detect if the user witch is authenticating through a Facebook account don't have already an "user" created with another authentication method? Because I don't want to create multiple users, to the same social auth account owner, or my own app account owner.
Can I get through this using the email column? So I can verify if the authenticating user already have a same e-mail registered in the "user" table, if he has, then I can create an identity with this same user_id?

Comment: Note that SHA1 (or any SHA) should not be used for storing passwords. They are not secure. check this [SO answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for better options.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, I would recommend that you add the user before you add the identity id. 
Check for existence of matching email before creating the user, then add the new identity.

I would have thought there should be a constraint on the identity that the user exists before creation. Otherwise you risk adding 'Identities' to the database with no connected user at all.